# No action is taken when Link to jira is clicked in UI in SonarQube 5.0

Tags: sonarqube, jira-plugin

I have set all the values in UI that are required by the jira issue plug-in. 
But 'Link to Jira' is working in SonarQube 4.5.1 and not on SonarQube 5.0 
No action is taken when Link to jira is clicked in UI in SonarQube 5.0 
Is it not configured in SonarQube 5.0?

SonarQube version 5.0 
Maven version 3.2.5

Answer (score 0):

This regression was indeed introduced in SonarQube 5.0, and it is fixed in upcoming SonarQube 5.1 thanks to [SONAR-6198](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-6198).